# SparkSQL Get all prefixes of a word

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a column in a SparkSQL DataFrame like this:

```
+-------+
|  word |
+-------+
| chair |
|  lamp |
| table |
+-------+
```

I want to explode out all the prefixes like so:

```
+--------+
| prefix |
+--------+
|      c |
|     ch |
|    cha |
|   chai |
|  chair |
|      l |
|     la |
|    lam |
|   lamp |
|      t |
|     ta |
|    tab |
|   tabl |
|  table |
+--------+
```

Is there a good way to do this WITHOUT using udfs, or functional programming methods such as `flatMap` in spark sql? (I'm talking about a solution using the codegen optimal functions in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`)

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is possible but I doubt it will perform any better than a simple `flatMap` (if performance is the reason to avoid `flatMap`):

```
val df = Seq("chair", "lamp", "table").toDF("word")
df.withColumn("len", explode(sequence(lit(1), length($"word"))))
  .select($"word".substr(lit(1), $"len") as "prefix")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+
|prefix|
+------+
|     c|
|    ch|
|   cha|
|  chai|
| chair|
|     l|
|    la|
|   lam|
|  lamp|
|     t|
|    ta|
|   tab|
|  tabl|
| table|
+------+
```